# error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, jenkins, cocoapods

I am facing this error when running my flutter project on IOS. This is the message that I am getting:

> "diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory"
>
> "diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory"
>
> "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod
> install' or update your CocoaPods installation."

I have used a couple of solutions to solve the problem such as "pod init", "pod install", "pod update", and I replaces the Check Pods Manifest.lock to "${SRCROOT}/Podfile.lock" "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Manifest.lock", but still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

this same issue was happening on our CICD build job. I tried deleting Pods_AppName.framework from Xcode -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries. Also there was issue with some dependency version conflicts but the logs were not shown as failure. Had to look carefully at the logs to find this one. fixing these two resolved the issue for me.